# Run Mongodb on android using Ionic 2

Tags: mongodb, angular, ionic2, localhost, database

I am trying to run mongodb on android using Ionic 2. I got my app to run in my pc browser and call data from the mongodb in the project folder, however it does not run on an actual device or emulator (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

I am following this tutorial 
https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-review-app-with-ionic-2-mongodb-node/

Answer (score 0):

You *CANNOT* use mongoDB in your front-end. MongoDB runs in a db server (in this case on your PC) and cannot be deployed in a mobile app. If you really have to use a noSQL datastore in your client then, go for pouchDB or its equivalent. pouchDB can also integrate with the cordova SQLite plugin and works well in ionic applications.
If you want to use mongoDB in the backend you can create REST API's like the tutorial has suggested to run queries on your mongoDB instance.
Another alternative would be to use [miniMongo](https://github.com/mWater/minimongo)